# Unable to implement google tag manager in Xamarin android due to error Invalid resource directory name for gtm-xxxx.json

Tags: android, json, xamarin.android, google-tag-manager

I am implementing Google tag manager in my Xamarin Android application using this reference link: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

As Steps mentioned in above link to add default container file in your project, I am trying to download container file, but i am getting GTM-XXXX.json not the binary file.

Also I am facing another problem while adding this JSON file in resource folder Resource/raw. Facing error: Invalid resource directory name: gtm-XXXX.json

Also i have referred below project sample from git hub: https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinTagManagerAndroid

Please suggest me solution to implement GTM in Xamarin Android.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to use one of the new Android containers with the older SDK. If you want to use the old SDK, you'll have to create an 'Android (legacy)' container, which will have a binary container file.

Comment: Hi Eric, I am using SDK version 32.940.0-beta3 of Tag Manager. Also we are using firebase analytics in our project, we can not create for 'Android (legacy)' so we are creating 'Android (Firebase) container. Please suggest me solution for Android(Firebase) container.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that SDK version number, is that a Xamarin supplied library?. If you're already using Firebase Analytics, you should be following the directions from the newer version of the SDK, which is here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/ . You'll need to reference the tagmanager dependency as described in that link (you'll want to match the same version of Google Play Services as you're using for Firebase Analytics)